# How to replace specific divs content with a countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a script that takes date (text) from between a div: `<div class="countdown"> DATE HERE </div>` and makes a countdown from it that refreshes every 1 second.

My question is: If I have multiple divs `<div class="countdown"> DATE HERE </div>`, how can I make the script to create countdowns from this divs automatically. My current script only works if it's only one div like this in page.

This is my script:

```
var targetDate = $(".countdown").text();
targetDate = new Date(targetDate).getTime();



// porneste counter-ul
setInterval(function() {

    var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
    var secondsLeft = (targetDate - currentDate) / 1000;


    var days = parseInt(secondsLeft / 86400);
    secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 86400;

    var hours = parseInt(secondsLeft / 3600);
    secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 3600;

    var minutes = parseInt(secondsLeft / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(secondsLeft % 60);


    // afiseaza data rezultata
    $(".countdown").html('<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="328" align="center"><tr>    <td width="82">'+days+'<span class="gray_text">d</span></td>    <td width="82">'+hours+'<span class="gray_text">h</span></td>    <td width="82">'+minutes+'<span class="gray_text">m</span></td>    <td width="82">'+seconds+'<span class="gray_text">s</span></td>    </tr></table>');   


}, 1000);
```

Comment: You have multiple `div` elements with class `countdown`, and you want to be able to target them differently, is that it?

Comment: Yes. I have different date on each div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `.each()`. Something like:

```
$('.countdown').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text(),
        targetDate = new Date(text).getTime();

    setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
        var secondsLeft = (targetDate - currentDate) / 1000;        

        var days = parseInt(secondsLeft / 86400);
        secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 86400;

        var hours = parseInt(secondsLeft / 3600);
        secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 3600;

        var minutes = parseInt(secondsLeft / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(secondsLeft % 60);

        // afiseaza data rezultata
        $this.html('<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="328" align="center"><tr>    <td width="82">'+days+'<span class="gray_text">d</span></td>    <td width="82">'+hours+'<span class="gray_text">h</span></td>    <td width="82">'+minutes+'<span class="gray_text">m</span></td>    <td width="82">'+seconds+'<span class="gray_text">s</span></td>    </tr></table>');   
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you have to add this instead my way?

`var $this = $(this), text = $this.text(), targetDate = new Date(text).getTime();`

Comment: @sorinu26 Inside of the `.each()` function, `this` will reference the DOM element for the current iteration. So if you have 3 '.countdown' divs, `$('.countdown').each(function() { console.log(this); })` will log each DOM element in the order it finds it on the page. The way you were doing it, `$('.countdown').text()` will only return the text for the FIRST element it finds using that selector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `each()` method?
If not, test it 
`$("div.countdown").each(function()
{
//do something.
});`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `$(".countdown").text();` to `$(".countdown:first-child").text();` so that only one text node is read. Otherwise `$(".countdown").text();` is going to be a string like `2013-10-11 2013-10-11 2013-10-11` which wont parse as a date correctly

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rKwU/)

Answer (score 0):

If all the divs contains the same date, you must get the date of the first (or any other...) so you must change thisline:

```
var targetDate = $($(".countdown")[0]).text();
```

If each div has its own date, then the solution is a little more difficult. You can set the initial value of each div and store it in a "data-x" attribute in DOM, then in your setinterval function you must set a loop and read the initial value stored for each div. For example, to store all values:

```
function storeDates(){
    $(".countdown").attr("data-initialDate", $(".countdown").html());}
```